# Parameter server with CPU only

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to do distributed training, I'm confused that since parameter server usaually does not use GPU, can we run parameter server on CPU only machines, I mean with no GPU, or disable GPU with something like `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''`, I tried this with TF object detection API, but it reports no GPU device available, I then tried `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.0001`, it works, but this is not a good solution, as it still take around 400MB gpu memory but does not use it. can some suggest something on this issue?

Comment: Parameter server should not need GPU. Most likely some part of the code specifically requests `with tf.device("GPU")`. If you can describe how you run it and provide the full stack trace of the error, folks will have easier time helping.

Comment: Have you tried to install tensorflow without GPU support on your parameter server's machine?